# Dynamic loading data to Form/Widget from DataBase

Tags: .net, database, qt, asynchronous, controls

Is there any Controls to show tables/trees from DB on-line? I mean without loading all data into application. At the moment any table/tree control can present no more than 50-100 items. Why i need to wait all data to be loaded? Where can i find more information about async loading data to table/tree widget from DB.

I am interested in such control in .NET and widget in Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt, `QSqlQueryModel`, `QSqlTableModel` and `QSqlRelationalTableModel` can load data from a database with minor configuration, you can then use these in a `QTableView` to show that loaded data